# Is the structure of sequence A094615 obvious?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, integers

Is the triangular structure described in [A094615](https://oeis.org/A094615) proven?
That is, is it proved that the following computation lasts forever?

\begin{eqnarray*}
3 &=& 2\cdot 1 + 1 \\
5 &=& 3\cdot 1 + 2 \\
\ \\
7 &=& 2\cdot 3 + 1 \\
11 &=& 2\cdot 5 + 1 = 3\cdot 3 + 2\\
17 &=& 3\cdot 5 + 2 \\
\ \\
15 &=& 2\cdot 7 + 1 \\
23 &=& 2\cdot 11 + 1 = 3\cdot 7 + 2\\
35 &=& 2\cdot 17 + 1 = 3\cdot 11 + 2\\
53 &=& 3\cdot 17 + 2\\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Thank you.

Comment: Is what you want to prove that the two calculations for a number not on the edge are always equal?

Comment: Hint for that: If we name the functions $f(x) = 2x+1$ and $g(x) = 3x+2$, any spot in the middle relates to an entry $N$ two rows above by $f(g(N))$ and $g(f(N))$.

Answer (score 2):

That linked page has an explicit representation of the entries given by Lamine Ngom, namely

$$T(n,k) = 2^{n+1-k}3^{k-1} -1 $$

Should be not too hard to verify by induction that the triangular pattern continues.